# app-flutter-openemr error on initialize them

Tags: flutter

I am trying to run
github.com/openemr/app-flutter-openemr
from Android Studio 4.1.2 with a simulator.

I got the Error:

The getter ‘body1’ isn’t defined for the class ‘TextTheme’
TextTheme’ is from ‘package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart’ (’…/…/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart’).
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named ‘body1’.
color ??= Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1.color;

I am new to flutter.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this file

[Your flutter directory]\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\charts_flutter-0.9.0\lib\src\behaviors\legend\legend_entry_layout.dart

change

```
  color ??= Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1.color;
```

at line  133

to

```
  color ??= Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.color;
```

Comment: Hi, I recommend you take a moment read [How can I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), after reading please update your answer, to feature reasoning and possibly a source/documentation to back up your answer. I understand that your answer may be helpful, but giving no explanation is sometimes worse than not answering at all, Kind Regards!